# Trying to display numbers when clicking button on CodePen

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, phone-number, codepen

I want to display the numbers selected at the top of their buttons. I'm currently using them to move an elevator — but I don't know how to print them to the screen.

I looked at some examples of calculators because it does what I want my code to do. When you enter the number with the button on the calculator, the same number shows up on the screen.

It uses a numbers-container class, but I'm not quite understanding how to get it to work.

https://codepen.io/yunaoh/pen/zYJdzOj

```js
var current = 0;

//Elevator animation
$(document).ready(function(){//to manipulate drawing

  $("#enterPhone button").click(function(){//when button is clicked
    
    var floor = parseInt($(this).data("floor"))
    height = floor*9.5 //reach top floor
    animate = Math.abs(current-floor)*1300;//elevator speed
    if(floor == current) return;
    $("#rightDoor").removeClass("active-right");//open right door   
    $("#leftDoor").removeClass("active-left");//open left door
    setTimeout(function(){$("#elevatorContainer").css("transition","all "+animate+"ms linear");
    $("#elevatorContainer").css("bottom",height+"%");
    current = floor;
    setTimeout(function(){
    
    $("#rightDoor").addClass("active-right");//close right door   
    $("#leftDoor").addClass("active-left");//close left door
    
    },animate);},350); //start to move after button clicked
  });

});
```

```css
#drawing {  
  font-family:footnotes;
  height:600px;
  width:100%;
  padding:40px 0;
  background-size:cover;
  
  #building {
    height:600px;
    width:15%;
    background:#383838;  
    margin:0 auto;
    overflow:hidden;
    box-shadow:0 -20px 0 #383838;
    
    #elevatorShaft {
      height:600px;
      width:32%;
      margin:0 auto;
      position:relative;
      background:#000000;
      
      #elevatorContainer {
        height:400px;
        width:100%;
        bottom:0;
        position:absolute;
        
        #elevator {
          height:20%;       
          width:100%;
          position:relative;
          box-shadow:0 -10px 0 #6B6B6B;
          overflow:hidden;//hide sliding doors
          background:#CFCFCF;
          background-size:100% 100%;
          
          .door {
            background:#AAAAAA;
            width:49%;
            height:100%;
            top:0;
            position:absolute;
            transition:all 300ms ease-in;
            
            &#leftDoor {
              left:0; 
            }
            &#rightDoor {
              right:0;
            }
          }
          .active-right {
            right:-50% !important;
          }
          .active-left {
            left:-50% !important;
          }
        }
        
        #strings {
          height:80%;
          width:75%;
          margin: 0 auto;
          background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, transparent, transparent 10%,#AAA 10%, #AAA 30%, transparent 30%, transparent 40%, #CCC 40%, #CCC 60%, transparent 60%, transparent 70%, #999 70%, #999 90%, transparent 90%, transparent);
        }
      }
    }
  }
  
  #enterPhone {
    position:absolute;
    background:#FFFFFF;
    width:15%;
    left:10%;
    box-shadow:0 0 5px #383838;
    
    ul {
      button { 
        font-family:footnotes;
        font-size:13px;
        height:30px;  
        width:30px;
        float:left;
        text-align:center;   
        line-height:22px;
        border:1px solid;
        margin:15px;
        border-radius:50%;
        border:3px solid #DDDDDD;//button rings
        background:#FFFFFF;
      
        &:hover {
          background:#656565;
          color:#FFFFFF;
          cursor:pointer;
        }
      }
    }
    
    h1 {
      text-align:center;
      font-size:15px;
      margin:20px 0 10px;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="drawing">

   <div id="enterPhone">
     <div class="output">
            <div data-previous class="previous"></div>
            <div data-current class="current"></div>
        </div>
     <h1>Enter your phone number</h1>
     <ul>
       <button data-floor="0">0</button>
       <button data-floor="1">1</button>
       <button data-floor="2">2</button>
       <button data-floor="3">3</button>
       <button data-floor="4">4</button>
       <button data-floor="5">5</button>
       <button data-floor="6">6</button>
       <button data-floor="7">7</button>
       <button data-floor="8">8</button>
       <button data-floor="9">9</button>
     </ul>
   </div>
  
  <div id="building">
    <div id="elevatorShaft">
      <div id="elevatorContainer">
        <div id="strings"></div>
          <div id="elevator">
            <div class="door active-left" id="leftDoor"></div>
            <div class="door active-right" id="rightDoor"</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

https://codepen.io/QuiteQuinn/pen/jOvYmJg

You can accomplish this by adding a class to your h1 HTML

```html
<h1 class="phone-number">Enter your phone number</h1>
```

And revising your javascript below so that it adds the floor number to a string and prints it to the above HTML.

```js
var current = 0;
/////////////
// Add a Global value variable
var value = "";
/////////////

// Elevator animation
$(document).ready(function(){//to manipulate drawing

  $("#enterPhone button").click(function(){//when button is clicked
    
    var floor = parseInt($(this).data("floor"))

    /////////////
    // Add floor to string + print string to screen
    value += floor;
    document.querySelector(".phone-number").innerHTML = value;
    /////////////

    height = floor*9.5 //reach top floor
    animate = Math.abs(current-floor)*1300;//elevator speed
    if(floor == current) return;
    $("#rightDoor").removeClass("active-right");//open right door   
    $("#leftDoor").removeClass("active-left");//open left door
    setTimeout(function(){$("#elevatorContainer").css("transition","all "+animate+"ms linear");
    $("#elevatorContainer").css("bottom",height+"%");
    current = floor;
    setTimeout(function(){
    
    $("#rightDoor").addClass("active-right");//close right door   
    $("#leftDoor").addClass("active-left");//close left door
    
    },animate);},350); //start to move after button clicked
  });

});
```